# How to set an Icon in Android using URL

Tags: java, android

I am using the WeatherOpenMap API in my app in order to get weather information about several cities. 
For example, if you have "broken clouds" as a weather condition, then the weatherFont icon changes to light blue.

```
 if (weather_description.equals("BROKEN CLOUDS"))                                                        
       weatherIcon.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0489B1")); // light blue
```

I am using Typeface:

```
 weatherFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplicationContext().getAssets(), "fonts/weathericons-regular-webfont.ttf");
 weatherIcon.setTypeface(weatherFont);
```

But now, I don't want to use this ttf file for my weatherIcon, I want to use hyperlinks, because it looks much better, so such as:

> http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png

which stands for moderate rain. But as you can see, this is an URL, how can I use this URL to change my weatherFont Icon when I have "moderate rain" as weather condition?

Thank you

Comment: download it, put it in res folder and use it!

Comment: Is this the only way ? Because there a lot of icons to download..

Comment: you shoudn't use URL for this. what happens if phone doesn't have internet connection? what if the URL is unreachable or Server is down?

Comment: If you don't have internet connection, you will get a toast message that says you don't have internet connection. If you don't have interneet connection at all, you can't use the weather feature in my app. I would surround it with a try/catch.

Comment: Still, downloading a bunch of images everytime you check the weather is going to be inefficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an image loading library like Picasso or Volley. Using Picasso, the code would look something like this:

```
String iconUrl = "https://...";
ImageView imgWeatherIcon = view.findViewById(R.id.imgWeatherIcon);
Picasso.with(context).load(iconUrl).into(imgWeatherIcon, new Callback()...
```